# How to do a find/replace with a regular expession in stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr, stringi

Given a string like 'run- ning' I would like to replace 'n- n' by 'nn' in order to obtain 'running'.

Using the stringr package I tried this:

```
str_replace_all(s, "[:alpha:]\\-([ ])+[:alpha:]", "[:alpha:][:alpha:]")
```

but it seems not to work that way. I guess variables need to be used, but I could figure out how exactly.

I tried this:

```
str_replace_all(s, "[:alpha:]\\-([ ])+[:alpha:]", "\\0\\1")
```

but that does not give the desired result either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
stringr::str_replace_all(s, "(?<=\\p{L})- +(?=\\p{L})", "")
stringr::str_replace_all(s, "(\\p{L})- +(\\p{L})", "\\1\\2")
```

Or, to match any horizontal whitespace chars

```
stringr::str_replace_all(s, "(?<=\\p{L})-\\h+(?=\\p{L})", "")
stringr::str_replace_all(s, "(\\p{L})-\\h+(\\p{L})", "\\1\\2")
```

Base R equivalent:

```
gsub("(?<=\\p{L})-\\h+(?=\\p{L})", "", s, perl=TRUE)
gsub("(\\p{L})-\\h+(\\p{L})", "\\1\\2", s, perl=TRUE)
gsub("([[:alpha:]])-\\s+([[:alpha:]])", "\\1\\2", s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JzhZPN/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=\p{L})` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with any Unicode letter
- `- +` - a hyphen followed with 1 or more spaces (`\h` matches any horizontal whitespace)
- `(?=\p{L})` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with any Unicode letter.
- `(\p{L})` - a capturing group that matches any letter.

The `\1\2` in the replacement patterns in the examples using capturing groups are backreferences to the corresponding capturing group values.